# Display Wordpress Post By Date

Tags: posts, wp-query

I want to show Wordpress post by day/date in homepage.

ex:

Monday, January 03

- post 1
- post 2
- post 3

Sunday, January 02

- post 1
- post 2
- post 3

Saturday, January 01

- post 1
- post 2
- post 3

What Wordpress query should I use?

Thanks. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

i think your question has been answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841514/group-posts-by-date-in-wordpress)

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'date' );
$myQuery = new WP_Query($args);
$date = '';
if ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) : while ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) : $myQuery->the_post();
if ( $date != get_the_date() ) {
    echo $date;
    echo '<hr />';
    $date = get_the_date();
}
the_title(); // or whatever you want here.
echo '<br />';
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

More info on the query here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Note that you would normally want to put the above code inside a template; optimally in a Child Theme, so that theme updates don't overwrite your changes